# check with voters single field in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, acl

I would like to know how to implement a check for a field inside voters of an entity.

I have for example my entity Post where I want that a user not admin can't edit title field. Only admin can edit this field.

So I have created my voters but I don't know how to create this check because inside `$post` there is the old post entity and I don't know how to implement the check for `title` field

This is my easy voters file

```
class PostVoter extends Voter
{
    const VIEW = 'view';
    const EDIT = 'edit';

    private $decisionManager;

    public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface $decisionManager)
    {
        $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::VIEW, self::EDIT))) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$subject instanceof Post) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(
        $attribute, 
        $subject, 
        TokenInterface $token
    ) {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->decisionManager->decide($token, array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'))) {
            return true;
        }

        /** @var Post $post */
        $post = $subject;

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW:
                return $this->canView($post, $user);
            case self::EDIT:
                return $this->canEdit($post, $user);
        }

        throw new \LogicException('This code should not be reached!');
    }

    private function canView(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        if ($this->canEdit($post, $user)) {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function canEdit(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        return $user === $post->getUser();
    }
}
```

I would like to implement inside canEdit a check for the title field.
I have tried to print $post but there is only old value not some information for new value.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to determine of the title has changed from inside of the voter?

Comment: Yes, or if isn't a better way tell me and I move this logic inside the controller or service. I don't really know the best approach to how to check a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of possible approaches.

The one I would use is to add a 'edit_title' permission to the voter then adjust my form to make the title read only if the edit_title permission was denied.  This not only eliminates the need to check for a changed title but also makes things a bit friendlier for the users.  One might imagine them being a bit frustrated with a form that allows them to change the title but then the app rejects the change.

If you really wanted to detect a title change then you could adjust the setTitle method in your post entity.  Something like:

```
class Post {
    private $titleWasChanged = false;
    public function setTitle($title) {
        if ($title !== $this->title) $this->titleWasChanged = true;
        $this->title = $title;
```

And then of course check $titleWasChanged from the voter.

If you really wanted to go all out, the Doctrine entity manager actually has some change checking capability.  You could probably access it via the voter but that would probably be overkill.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html

Comment: very interesting solutions! I will try It.
Thanks a lot